# Non-ascii in Cygwin bash command line causes error

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm calling bash from cmd.exe like this

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "echo ф"
```

and get on Cygwin 2.8.0

```
/usr/bin/bash: echo ф: command not found
```

It treats the parameter as part of the command name. Doing the same on Cygwin 2.5.2 I get the output `ф`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the Φ that's causing the problem? Does it work if you run `c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "echo f"`?

Comment: @terdon I can confirm that `"echo ф"` (and `"echo å"` etc.) fails while `"echo f`" works. I don't know if this is at all related to `bash` though, or if it's a `cmd.exe` thing.

Comment: Can you confirm that the character between "echo" and "ф" is a plain ASCII space rather than something like a non-breaking space?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson It's a plain ascii space.

Answer (score 8):

Since this used to work, and works fine for people running bash on Unices (I tested on Debian here), I think you've found a Cygwin bug. The Cygwin project has a page about [reporting Cygwin bugs](https://cygwin.com/problems.html). They have a bunch of useful information and steps there, far too long to summarize here.

In the meantime, I suspect you can work around this by escaping the character. Bash's `echo`, when given the `-e` flag, interprets various escape sequences:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "echo -e '\xd1\x84'"
```

should work. Hexadecimal `D1 84` is the UTF-8 encoding of ф. If you have the `unicode` tool, it'll tell you—but so will just echoing the character to `od` or `xxd`:

```
$ echo -n 'ф' | od -t x1
0000000 d1 84
0000002

$ echo -n 'ф' | xxd -p
d184
```

The Cygwin FAQ tells me it uses UTF-8 by default, so that should work. But of course you can use other encodings too (I think [Windows mostly uses UTF16le](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986787/what-is-the-default-unicode-character-encoding-used-in-windows)):

```
$ echo -n 'ф' | iconv -t utf16le | xxd -p
4404
```

Comment: FWIW, `"echo -e '\xd1\x84'"` works.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, I don't have any Cygwin installs to test with.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `cmd.exe` adds an additional pair of quotes around arguments with non-ASCII characters.
So what actually arrives at the cygwin application is the following:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "echo blo"
arg0: /usr/bin/bash
arg1: --login
arg2: -c
arg3: echo blo
```

So bash can interpret '`echo blo`', but:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "echo blöd"
arg0: /usr/bin/bash
arg1: --login
arg2: -c
arg3: "echo blöd"
```

Now bash does not recognize '`"echo blöd"`'.

Answer (score 1):

The analysis from user1274247 is the right one.

We therefore need to find a way to strip the leading and trailing quotes, when cmd.exe doubles them without our knowing.

I was having the exact same issue when dealing with paths containing spaces, single quotes and non-ascii characters.
I solved it by separating the bash command to execute (aka `-c`) and the problematic string parameter.

According to bash man:

```
-c string
If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

Our command therefore becomes:

```dos
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -lc 'a="${0%\"}"; a="${a#\"}";echo "$a"; sleep 10' "C:\spa ces\quo'tes\nonàscîï"
```

Or, if you prefer using the mintty terminal:

```dos
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash -lc 'a="${0%\"}"; a="${a#\"}";echo "$a"; sleep 10' "C:\spa ces\quo'tes\nonàscîï"
```

And if you wanna use it in regedit (to launch a bash command when right-clicking a file), here's the proper escaping (for quotes and %):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Test]
@="echo filename in bash"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Test\command]
@="C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/bash -lc ' a=\"${0%%\\\"}\"; a=\"${a#\\\"}\";echo \"$a\"; sleep 10 ' \"%1\""
```

I'm using it, for example, to duplicate files (extract from a bigger toolbox):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate]
@="Duplicate file"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Duplicate\command]
@="C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe /bin/bash -lc ' a=\"${0%%\\\"}\"; a=\"${a#\\\"}\" ; cd \"$(dirname \"$(cygpath \"$a\")\")\"; f=\"$(basename \"$a\")\" ; n=\"$(basename \"$a\" \".${f##*.}\")\" ; cp \"${f}\" \"${n}-copy.${f##*.}\"   ' \"%1\" "
```